# Why CR sequence (\r) getting entered in .vimrc file?

Tags: vim, newlines

Please look at my '~/.vimrc' file below.

```
:map g :w
:map g :w
```

See, the same line repeated. After writing 1st line, I pressed the "Enter" key.

Now see the output of the od command below.

```
ravi@ravi-Aspire-5315:~$ od -bc .vimrc
0000000 072 155 141 160 040 147 040 072 167 015 012 072 155 141 160 040
          :   m   a   p       g       :   w  \r  \n   :   m   a   p    
0000020 147 040 072 167 015 012
          g       :   w  \r  \n
0000026
ravi@ravi-Aspire-5315:~$
```

I am wondering why the CR (\r) sequence getting entered here as this is Linux and not a Windows machine.

Now I change the contents of the .vimrc file as below:

```
:set showmode
```

Now when I run the `od` command, it outputs:

```
ravi@ravi-Aspire-5315:~$ od -bc .vimrc
0000000 072 163 145 164 040 163 150 157 167 155 157 144 145 015 012
          :   s   e   t       s   h   o   w   m   o   d   e  \r  \n
0000017
```

Now `vim` is throwing error whenever I am opening any file via the command `vim`

```
vim .vimrc
Error detected while processing /home/ravi/.vimrc:
line    1:
E488: Trailing characters: showmode^M
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

I understand the error is due to the CR (\r) sequence which is same as "^M".

> 2 questions

1)
Why `vim` threw error with the `set` command for the `\r` sequence but didn't throw with the `map` command.

2)
To a big surprise, why `\r` getting entered as this is Linux and not Windows machine. I am working on Ubuntu 15.10.

Comment: What do `set fileformat` and `set fileformats` return?

Answer (score 1):

Normally, a line such as

```
:map g :w
```

would have a literal **`^M`** ending, to allow the user's map-command to complete without having to press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

If the `.vimrc` is short enough, e.g., consisting only of a few lines, where the majority have **`^M`** endings, vim will guess that the file uses DOS (carriage-return / line-feed) endings, and store updates to the file using that convention — throughout.

For further reading

- [*23.1*  DOS, Mac and Unix files](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_23.html) (Vim documentation)
- [fileformats](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27fileformats%27) (Vim documentation)
- [File format](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/File_format) (Vim wiki)
- [Convert DOS line endings to Linux line endings in vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82726/convert-dos-line-endings-to-linux-line-endings-in-vim)

The file `.vimrc` is like any other text file: vim will guess *its* line-endings when reading it.  In fact, you should be able to make a file containing two ^M's at the end of the original file: (1) for ending the `map` command, and (1) for ending the lines.

Comment: I think this convention has come into vim recently as nearly 2 yrs back, this wasn't a convention. Linux or Vim never ended with CR-LF earlier, it ended only with LF.

Comment: It's been around a while.  Start with the documentation for [`fileformats`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27fileformats%27)

Comment: `^M` signifies what? CR (\r) sequence or LF (\n) sequence? I read in a book: at one place it was written, `^M` represents CR (\r) sequence. In the same book at other place it was written `^M` signifies the `Enter` key and in Linux `Enter` key is `LF` sequence.

Comment: Vim has **guessed** at file-format since the early 1990s.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I feel I will get the answer there.